# Getting a Constant Value From ADC

Tags: adc

I run a 10bit ADC from which I get a number which varies in-between +/-5.
Ex:- if ADC value is 512 then it may vary from any number in between 517 and 507.

I do not want to use any filter mechanism as it is computationally intensive.
I just want to get a pick a fixed number from last 10 measurements which has more frequency.
Please help me in writing a function for above.

Microcontroller- infineonTLE
IDE- Keil(c)

Comment: `number which varies in-between +/-5`  ... sounds like a filter to me

Comment: Determining the maximum of the last X values might actually need more computational power (and a lot more memory) than just using a simple IIR (infinite impulse response) filter. I think you're worrying about a problem that doesn't even exist. Just write an IIR filter and see how many CPU cycles it needs.

Comment: you are making too many assumptions with your question ... you are assuming that all programming languages are the same, since you did not specify one .... you are also assuming that all ADCs are the same since you did not specify which one you are using

Comment: You want a filter mechanism. E.g. adding up the lastest 10 values, then dividing by 10 is a simple FIR filter.

Comment: Or add a filter capacitor to your ADC input.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan S, Please help me in writting a IIR filter. in my opinion a IIR filter works like   New output = old output + coefficient A * input - coefficient B * old output.           Correct?

Comment: The difference between FIR and IIR is FIR uses the input sequence as inputs only, while IIR uses the computed output result as an input, too. This makes it possible to shorten the state fifo to very few stages. You may try it with one old stage.

Comment: Even with an electronic filter on the input, you'll often see some variation in the output reading between more than just adjacent counts; *especially* if extreme care hasn't been taken in the design of the board.  To get really quiet ADC readings it is sometimes advisable to temporarily shut down other parts of circuitry.  Your simplest outcome could be to decide that *any* of the readings are "close enough", next filtering if that gets you useful values.  Redesign and quieting can be huge wins, but also substantial projects.

Comment: Thanks all for your support. I have decided to go with IIR filter as i need it for some other application. I am working on it.

Comment: A running average is a computationally cheap FIR filter (with a rectangular impulse response, and thus a sinc function frequency response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple 1-stage IIR filter:

```
float state = 0;

float filter(float sample)
{
    state = (1 * sample + 0.2 * state)/1.2;

    return state;
}
```

You can tweak the response by changing the coefficients before *sample* and *state*. Don't forget to adjust the coefficient sum, too.

For more knobs to tweak, you can remember the previous, pre-previous etc. states, too.

```
float states[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

float filter(float sample)
{
    float latest;

    latest = (1 * sample + 0.2 * states[0] + 0.1 * states[1] + 0.05 * states[2])/1.35;

    states[2] = states[1];
    states[1] = states[0];
    states[0] = latest;

    return latest;
}
```

Comment: So far as I know IIR filters have feedback from output!!!Correct?

Comment: Yes. That's why the output of the filter function is fed into the internal "state" variable/array variable in the functions above.

Comment: Thanks Janka, by trial and error i got latest = (0.01 * sample + 0.3 * states[0] + 0.3 * states[1] + 0.01 * states[2])/0.62; Stability is excellent. I think there is a lot of theory on finding out the exact coefficient.

Comment: *Tweaking is okay*, because stability considerations always have to include the complete regulation loop, and retrieving information about all these components can be **hard**.

Answer (score 1):

As this is an EE site I'm going to show how a simple IIR digital filter mimics an RC low pass filter: -

[image]

- Stage 1 - the RC filter
- Stage 2 - convert this to an op-amp filter
- Stage 3 - rearrange the op-amp circuit to make it an integrator
- Stage 4 - Convert stage 3 to a simple IIR filter